# How to Convert Types Using Reflection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, casting, gettype

Please consider this Code:

```
string propertyValue = "1";
PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");
info.SetValue(detail, Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, info.PropertyType), null);
```

The problem is type of `info.PropertyType` is `System.Byte?` and when the line 3 wants to be executed I got this Error:

> "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Byte, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'."}

How I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is unrelated to reflection. The issue is simply that `Convert.ChangeType` cannot convert from `System.String` to `System.Byte?`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thanks but What should I do? I have some types and some values that should converted.

Comment: It would be best to rephrase your question (at the very least the title and the tags) to reflect the actual conversion problem. Also, please outline whether you know the destination type at design time in some way (e.g. is it one out of a very small set?), or whether it can be virtually anything. The underlying issue here seems to be transforming a string into a `byte` value that is then assigned to a `Nullable<byte>`, but it is not clear yet whether `byte` might be anything else ...

Comment: @Arian If you're certain that propertyValue is not null: `Byte.Parse(propertyValue)` should work

Comment: ... because, as @vc74's comment has just illustrated, otherwise you may be getting solutions that work if you already know what the target type is, but not so much if the target type can be an arbitrary `Type`.

Comment: @vc74 The problem is The type I should convert is not `System.Byte` always and I have multiple types

Comment: @Arian Then you can use Waescher's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is better:

```
PropertyInfo info = detail.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

var targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType);
if (targetType == null)
    targetType = info.PropertyType;

object safeValue = (propertyValue == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, targetType);

info.SetValue(detail, safeValue, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ChangeType()` has issues with nullable types.
Try to check if the type is nullable first. If so, take the underlying type:

```
var targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType);
if (targetType == null)
    targetType = info.PropertyType;
```

You may then call `Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, targetType)`.

Unfortunately this will bring you to another issue: `ChangeType()` won't convert `"1"` or `"0"` to booleans. However it works with `"true"` and `"false"`. It also works with `0` and `1` as integers.

[Check the fiddle I prepared for you](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ehSPYg)

This issue might be a problem for you or not - I don't know the specs the values are coming from.